# Is there any console that supports Java on their Internet browser?

Tags: ps3, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, psp

I do want to play some flash games (for example, Runescape) on a console, i own the Ps3, Wii U, 3DS and PSP that have internet connection, and i buy legit games for them, so i don't want to modify the console or anything.
**Is it possible to load Java on those consoles?**

It would be cool to play games like RS on those, the Ps3 has the keyboard supports, and the Wii U...well, it got a touchscreen...it would be perfect.

Comment: The PS3 can but you need to install Ubuntu first.

Comment: Only older PS3s that still have old firmware can install Linux without modifying the console. The 3D performance would be poor because it doesn't have access to the 3D hardware.

Comment: What about the latest firmware? can i do something for that?

Comment: You can apparently downgrade the firmware on the PS3, but that would mean softmodding your console. Something like Runescape would play like slide show, assuming you were even able to get it to run. See this post on the performance of Minecraft when run on PS3 Linux: http://psx-scene.com/forums/f119/run-minecraft-ps3-via-linux-84921/

Comment: Are you asking about Java or Flash or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no current gen, or previous gen consoles which will do this without modification of some sort.

It's possible if you have the right model of PS3 you could install Linux on it, and do it via this, but other than that you won't have any luck I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1):

When the HTML5 beta was still available, it was possible to play RS3 on the Wii U's browser. It lagged like hell, but worked.

Right now, however, it's impossible to get RuneScape to run on consoles without modding them, as none of them have Java installed.